# How difficult is it to install Microsoft Office on Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I have never used Ubuntu before.  I have only ever used Windows, and I am thinking of installing Ubuntu as it seems to have far less bloatware and I am sick of the constant updates from Windows.

However, I would require Microsoft Office installed on the Ubuntu system. Watching youtube videos, they seem to use a command prompt and the process to install it seems really confusing. can someone confirm the process

Other alternatives to Microsoft Office are not really suitble.

Comment: Why Libreoffice is not good for you? It can read|write `docx`, etc files. You don't need command prompt to watch Youtube. You need it to download videos.

Comment: The problem I ran in to with using libre instead was it didn't include project or visio.  So, there is that.  They were hard requirements for a few courses in college, and that gap is not yet filled.

Comment: You can install older MSO with Playonlinux. But it's not always very easy indeed.

Comment: Yeah, but edge office is all webapp available.  So, I use that now.  I put in the caveats that made me need it in a comment above.

Comment: "Other alternatives to Microsoft Office are not really suitble."  with just that statement I will claim libre office is on par with office besides macros. And VisualBasic macros should be avoided  anyways. @RobotHumans Libre office draw can do what visio can and then some.